# How to hook up SqlDataAdapter to profile db operations with mvc mini profiler

Tags: profiler, mvc-mini-profiler

I looked up [How could I instantiate a Profiled DataAdapter to use with MVC MINI PROFILER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925314/how-could-i-instantiate-a-profiled-dataadapter-to-use-with-mvc-mini-profiler) but this also did not answer my question.

I have some code like this in SqlDatasource class -

```
protected SqlCommand sqlCommand;

public SqlDatasource(String query, String connectionString) : this(connectionString)
    {
        this.sqlCommand.CommandText = query;
    }

public DataTable getResults()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(this.sqlCommand);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }
```

I want a way to hook into the SqlDataAdapter when getResults() gets called. I searched a lot but there did not seem a way for me to do this yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I should mention that I am making use of it in a Nunit test project so I have mocked the httpcontext and I have no web.config with mee.

Comment: Ok now I am being able to hook into ado.net because I was able to get a wrapper for sqlconnection. But still the profiler is not logging sql timings. This is because HasSqlTimings is set to false. Do I have to specifically set to True?

Comment: This was a bug and has been fixed - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171922/miniprofiler-profileddbdataadapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a class `ProfiledDbDataAdapter` provided for this that you can use wrapped around your existing `SqlDataAdapter`.

When I tried using it I found I needed to use the `Fill(DataSet)` method instead of `Fill(DataTable)` else I always received an error "The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'." despite setting both adapter's `SelectCommand` properties.